# Windows hotkey to change keyboard layout

Tags: windows, shortcuts, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

What is the hotkey to switch between keyboard layouts in windows, while in some application? I tried CTRL+shift and ALT+shift but it didn't work.

Comment: Try **Left** Alt+Shift. Also specify your version of Windows.

Comment: `Alt+Shift` - Windows 7   and  `Win button + Space` Win 8  and 10

Comment: you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 15):

On Windows 10 press Win + Space to cycle through the languages.
You may need to press multiple times until you see the overlay.

Comment: The best way to do it! Alt+Shif only pops the box with keyboard langs but you have to click on it to switch

Answer (score 5):

For me, it's CTRL+SHIFT to switch between keyboard layouts within the same language culture. I never set this manually, and I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: although there is no feedback on the screen, the language bar still says, US keyboard, but that is the global working answer

Comment: Yes I still wonder who on earth came up with that. Every time you press something like Ctrl+Shift+F (global find in some IDEs for example) it silently changes the layout. And it's so hard to find that settings dialog to disable it.