# Some keyboard keys do not work correctly (Alt, ctrl, alt, was jammed)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, keyboard-layout

I have a problem: my keyboard at a certain point starts to change the layout, for example:

- ESC -> win and SHIFT together
- SHIFT -> alt + tab, if i press it twice, it changes the language.
- The mouse can close google windows

Also, when I try to press the space bar, the right click works, but the window closes almost immediately as if I was spamming with it.

That's all I remember and can somehow understand. Next, my keyboard stops writing, my key selects all shortcuts and right clicks the shortcut if I left clicked.
There is no num pad on my keyboard. (just in case)

My model is : Blazing Pro RGB.

Model of mouse: ARDW-FURY3325-BK

Also it feels like some button has been jammed, because the mouse highlights a certain area. like I somehow clicked on one of the shortcuts.

Turns out the reason why its hapening is because my mouse got some bad drivers

Comment: What are your computer and keyboard models?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10 & https://superuser.com/questions/1130835/windows-hotkey-to-change-keyboard-layout Delete all keyboard layouts except the one you use

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: my model is :Blazing Pro RGB

Comment: @Gantendo didnt worked, cause i use both (Russian (main) and english), i deleted one,  but i dowload it again. cause... you know... im using this one right now.

Comment: If you believe a key is jammed, the quickest test is to use a different keyboard and see if the issues persist. If the issues are resolved, you need to repair or replace your original keyboard. If the problems continue, the issue is in software.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the suggestion about deleting all the keyboard layouts that you don't use doesn't work, it could be one of two problems. Either you need to do a very thorough cleaning of your keyboard and mouse, using canned air. Or, you may have a virus. I ran into both situations when I had my computer shop. Hope this helps.

Comment: I checked my pc for viruses, turns out, some of my drivers got an error, so it did help me out. thanks!

Comment: Turns out my mouse has some very bad drivers that cause the problem (ARDW-FURY3325-BK). And the buttons was jammed is CTRL, ALT and SHIFT